# SQL Server : query that doesn't work with parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not sure why this query works one way and not the other.

If I use the following query:

```
Select 
    dlb.referenceid, dlb.partnum, 
    pd.width, pd.length,
    dlb.partqty,
    Convert(date, dlb.entrydatetime, 101) as entrydatetime,
    dlb.status, dlb.material 
From 
    tbl_dlbase dlb 
Join 
    tbl_partdetails pd On dlb.referenceid = pd.referenceid 
Where 
    (pd.Spacing = 3) 
    And ((dlb.status = 'Available') or (dlb.status = 'Reserved')) 
Order By 
    dlb.status
```

It returns one result as it should.

[image]

If I use the exact same query but with parameters:

```
Select 
    dlb.referenceid, dlb.partnum,
    pd.width, pd.length,
    dlb.partqty,
    Convert(date, dlb.entrydatetime, 101) as entrydatetime,
    dlb.status, dlb.material 
From 
    tbl_dlbase dlb 
Join 
    tbl_partdetails pd On dlb.referenceid = pd.referenceid 
Where 
    (@parameter1 = @Criteria1) 
    And ((dlb.status = 'Available') or (dlb.status = 'Reserved')) 
Order By 
    dlb.status
```

And have the following parameters declared and set as follows:

```
Declare @parameter1 varchar(50)
Declare @Criteria1 varchar(50)
Set @parameter1 = 'pd.Spacing'
Set @Criteria1 = 3
```

The query returns no results.

[image]

I have used this type parameter query many times before but for some reason this time it won't work. Can anyone tell me what stupid thing I am missing or screwed up? I can't seem to see anything wrongs with it.

Comment: you can't use parameters as object names without dynamic sql

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I have been able to do this same type of query before. Are you saying must have been dumb luck that it worked?

Comment: `(@parameter1 = @Criteria1) AND` ? You are comparing two parameters agains each other. Unless they are equal (which means the check is pointless) the `WHERE` statement will be false always

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the *field* name as a parameter? There are probably better ways to do it that don't require dynamic SQL, eg create a view or function for the common case and add the extra constraint as needed. Or create two different stored procedures that use the same view with different `status` criteria. Or use LINQ to add the extra condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use parameters as object names without dynamic sql. Here is a fix... just change the print to `exec(@sql)` when you are happy with it...

```
Declare @parameter1 varchar(50)
Declare @Criteria1 varchar(50)
Set @parameter1 = 'pd.Spacing'
Set @Criteria1 = '3'

declare @sql varchar(max) 
set @sql =
'Select 
    dlb.referenceid, 
    dlb.partnum, 
    pd.width, 
    pd.length, 
    dlb.partqty, 
    Convert(date, dlb.entrydatetime, 101) as entrydatetime, 
    dlb.status, 
    dlb.material 
From tbl_dlbase dlb 
Join tbl_partdetails pd On 
dlb.referenceid = pd.referenceid
Where (' + @parameter1 + ' = ' + @Criteria1 + ') 
AND ((dlb.status = ''Available'') OR (dlb.status = ''Reserved'')) 
Order By dlb.status'

print @sql
--exec(@sql)
--sp_executesql @sql
```

This makes your where clause `Where (pd.Spacing = 3)` otherwise  the where clause is simply comparing the parameters, which obviously aren't the same since they aren't set to the same thing. It's the same thing as writing:

```
Select 'True'
where @parameter1 = @Criteria1
```

which is interpreted as

```
Select 'True'
where 'pd.Spacing'= '3'    --string literals, not column names.
```

Comment: So I am assuming that I should make this a stored procedure then and just pass the parameters to the sproc from my vb code then?

Comment: @mbcharney see my last edit. That won't matter unless you use dynamic sql or

Comment: I tried the code you posted but management studio threw an error back at me. The name (And then lists the query syntax) is not a valid identifier. The code looked good to me so i am not sure what the error from?

Comment: what was the exact error? If you run it as it, you will see the print statement that will be executed. So, i'm not sure where the error could be

Comment: I changed it to exec and the error was:

The name [Then listed the whole query] is not a valid identifier

The print command worked fine

Comment: Here is the exact error:

Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 27
The name 'Select 
    dlb.referenceid, 
    dlb.partnum, 
    pd.width, 
    pd.length, 
    dlb.partqty, 
    Convert(date, dlb.entrydatetime, 101) as entrydatetime, 
    dlb.status, 
    dlb.material 
From tbl_dlbase dlb 
Join tbl_partdetails pd On 
dlb.referenceid = pd.referenceid
Where (pd.Spacing = 3) 
AND ((dlb.status = 'Available') OR (dlb.status = 'Reserved')) 
Order By dlb.status' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: try the edit above @mbcharney I think it doesn't like the sql being set with the declaration. I made this a separate line.

Comment: @mbcharney you may have forgotten the prackets on the exec statement. It needs to be exec(@sql). I also added another way using sp_executesql

Comment: Yep.Stupid mistake. Forgot the brackets....
Thanks for the help that will work great!